# How to write a simple web application using native ruby?

Tags: ruby

I am new to the Ruby programming language and I'm having a hard time writing a simple web application that outputs 'hello world' on an html page. I heard about Ruby on Rails but for me, I want to start from the beginning before using more advance frameworks.

Comment: Which one is your actual question?

Comment: Read the documentation on the [`net/http`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html) library, included with Ruby as part of the standard library, if you _really_ want to "start from the origin". I would not do that, however. I would learn the Ruby language _separate_ from the web (e.g. [Ruby Koans](http://rubykoans.com/) or [Ruby Quiz](http://www.rubyquiz.com)) and _then_ use a simple web framework like Rack or Sinatra.

Comment: If you're trying to use Ruby like PHP, you can't.  You need a framework before Ruby becomes useful... Ruby isn't pre-processed markup like PHP is... you need to deal with sending and receiving HTTP data.

Comment: If you want to do this without any dependencies from scratch you are going to have to learn about HTTP http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol and TCP/IP http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP/IP_model and http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/socket/rdoc/Socket.html ... it is a lot of work

Answer (score 5):

Ruby is a general-purpose language. It is not intended to be embedded inside HTML like PHP. So if you want to learn it from scratch write console applications instead of web apps. Here is a "hello world" ruby program:

```
puts "Hello, world!"
```

If you save it to the `hello_world.rb` you can run it with `ruby hello_world.rb` and you will see `Hello world` printed. There is a nice tool called `irb` that allows you to write a code and see the result immediately without having to save it to the file and run it manually. I would recommend you to use it to experiment with Ruby.

```
$ irb
>> puts "Hello, world"
Hello, world
=> nil
```

Good luck with learning!

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/). It's pretty much the lowest level you can get to without invoking your script as a CGI application and manually parsing out the headers.

Comment: so is it not possible to create an application using native ruby language?i mean like php you can output a simple Hello world without using a lib or framework.

Comment: Yes, it is, using CGI, although the amount of effort required to do this is astronomical.

Comment: @pacificindio you can do that with pretty much any language...but to think it requires no "lib or framework" is probably wrong.

Comment: so i need an extra effort just to output simple string. Anyways i want to begin from the very start to know how ruby works.

Comment: If you want to figure out how Ruby works, you're going about this the wrong way. Ruby is just a programming language, you can figure out how it works simply by learning the language and its standard library, and run it in a Ruby shell. Web applications are an entirely different (and more complex) kettle of fish.

Comment: @keith.layne Im not ready to learn ruby on rails i just want to start from the very beginning like Normal PHP to advance frameworks. like Ruby on Ruby on rails something like that.

Comment: Ruby on Rails and Ruby are completely (ish) different things. Learn Ruby first in a shell, then move on to more advanced concepts.

Comment: @keith.layne - yep. I've actually seen it used in projects before to get a very quick server up and running, simply because the person in question knew it and could throw it together quickly.